# How do you SELECT MAX() inside an INSERT in MYSQL to automatically increase the customerNumber

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to add a new row in the table which will add the following but then automatically increment the customerNumber by one to a new value from the table. I have tried it out with variables and it worked but I need to do this query in one operation.

```
INSERT INTO customers (customerNumber,customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(customerNumber)+1 FROM customers),'Detectives Inc.', 'Holmes', 'Sherlock', '2743824490', '221B Baker Street', 'Apt 2', 'London', 'LL', '50876', 'England');
```

This is what I have been trying but I get an error "You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause"

**EDIT**

I resolved the issue by doing the following query

> INSERT INTO customers (customerNumber,customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country)
> SELECT MAX(customerNumber)+1 ,'Detectives Inc.', 'Holmes', 'Sherlock', '2743824490', '221B Baker Street', 'Apt 2', 'London', 'LL', '50876', 'England'
> FROM customers;

Comment: Use an auto increment column instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sub-query and try as follows:

```
...
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(customerNumber)+1 from (select customernumber FROM customers) t),'Detectives Inc.'
...
```

Comment: I have gotten an error saying "Every derived table must have its own alias" after trying the sub-query. I am just thinking is it a problem with my workbench or does it not work that way?

Comment: Just gave the alias `t` . Check the updated answer.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can directly solve your problem using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO customers (customerNumber,customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country)
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(customerNumber)+1, 1), 'Detectives Inc.', 'Holmes', 'Sherlock', '2743824490', '221B Baker Street', 'Apt 2', 'London', 'LL', '50876', 'England'
    FROM customers;
```

Now, let me explain that you *never* want to do this.  First, MySQL supports `auto_increment` columns which does this automatically.  It is usually better to let the database do things that the database natively supports.

More importantly, your code does not guarantee a unique id.  Two insert queries can run at the same time -- and return the same count.  Or, you can set up locking on the table so this doesn't happen.  That significantly slows down queries.